# Apache Camel ValueBuilder case insensitive

Tags: apache-camel

How can I handle equalsIgnoreCase?

The following can only handle isEqualTo, would it be possible to do this without making anything inside a processor?

```
@Test
public void testPreicateProperties() throws Exception {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:a")
                .setProperty("A", constant("ab"))
                .setProperty("B", constant("aB"))
                .setHeader("A",  constant("ab"))
                .setHeader("B", constant("aB"))
                .choice()
                    .when(PredicateBuilder.and(exchangeProperty("A").isEqualTo(exchangeProperty("B"))))
                        .log("Equal properties")
                    .otherwise()
                        .log("Not Equal properties")
                .endChoice()
                .choice()
                    .when(PredicateBuilder.and(header("A").isEqualTo(header("B"))))
                        .log("Equal headers")
                    .otherwise()
                        .log("Not Equal headers")
                ;
        }
    });

    template.sendBody("direct:a", "body");

    Thread.sleep(1500);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such support currently. But there is a similar ticket to add that.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8832

That ticket will add equalsIgnoreCase support in the simple language and also for the value builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Simple` Language (see [here](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)) to create a regex, and then configure it to be be case insensitive.

See this line :

```
when(exchangeProperty("A").matches(constant("${exchangeProperty.B}/i")))
```

It uses the property B to generate a regex, in which /i indicate "insensitive". Then, it matches the regex with property A.